# Would a personal check be rejected solely on the basis of an inaccurate bank address?

Tags: check, personal-check

I wonder if there is any chance for a personal check to be denied solely due to an inaccurate bank address. I ordered a book of personal checks from Amazon. However, the company seems to mix my bank's mail and corporate addresses together. It is still perfectly understandable. However, I am not sure if I should request corrected reprints or just use the present "okay" ones.

Comment: I'd return, and request they be re-printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was going to start with a comment, but this turned into an answer.

This is also a US based answer.

In the united states the most important information on a blank check are the routing number and the account number.

A few years ago my credit union main office moved across the river into the neighboring state. The name of the credit union didn't change, just the mailing address. It went from a PO Box in Maryland to a physical address in Virginia.

In our house we recently got a new box of checks with the Virginia address. We are currently using the last 25 checks with the old address. At no time has it caused a problem. The credit union didn't require people to get new checks when the bank moved.

The reason the bank address doesn't make a difference is that the checks are processed with that being a piece of required information. The routing number is the key. That lets system know which bank will be honoring the check.

So if the bank routing number is correct, and your account number is correct, then you should be fine. Now if the name of the bank changed that could be a problem. Many websites that ask for the routing number, do a lookup and as a verification show you the name of the bank. It might be possible that a system that relied on that matching could reject a bank name change, but I would think the system could handle that also.